# What are formatted string literals in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

One of the features of Python 3.6 are formatted strings.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745050/string-with-f-prefix-in-python-3-6)(String with 'f' prefix in python-3.6) is asking about the internals of formatted string literals, but I don't understand the exact use case of formatted string literals. In which situations should I use this feature? Isn't explicit better than implicit?

Comment: For example generating queries for query languages (should use prepared queries where available) or you want a single string that has variable parameters like a list or formatted float etc.

Comment: I think this is somewhat broad and/or opinion-based, but I see three benefits: 1) it's shorter; 2) impossible to mess up the order of parameters in `format` (you can use named parameters, but then it's _much_ shorter); 3) immediately clear which variable goes where without jumping back and forth between format string and parameter list.

Comment: Beware of f-strings! They are _extremely_ addictive. After a few days of using them it's hard to go back to other kinds of formatting. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String with 'f' prefix in python-3.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745050/string-with-f-prefix-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Simple is better than complex.

So here we have formatted string. It gives the simplicity to the string formatting, while keeping the code explicit (comprared to other string formatting mechanisms).

```
title = 'Mr.'
name = 'Tom'
count = 3

# This is explicit but complex
print('Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.'.format(title=title, name=name, count=count))

# This is simple but implicit
print('Hello %s %s! You have %d messages.' % (title, name, count))

# This is both explicit and simple. PERFECT!
print(f'Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.')
```

It is designed to replace `str.format` for simple string formatting.

Comment: While I agree, one could argue that the former _could_ be written much shorter as `'Hello {} {}! You have {} messages.'.format(title, name, msg_count)`

Comment: well, it's very "implicit" when you have a dozen of `{}`s in the string

Comment: Agreed again, but that means that it's not just brevity. Its brevity while retaining the explicitness of having the actual variable names in the format string. (On second thought, I think that's exactly what you were trying to say... +1)

Answer (score 3):

Pro: F-literal has better performance.(See below)

Con: F-literal is a new 3.6 feature.

```
In [1]: title = 'Mr.'
   ...: name = 'Tom'
   ...: count = 3
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [2]: %timeit 'Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.'.format(title=title, name=name, count=count)
330 ns ± 1.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit 'Hello %s %s! You have %d messages.'%(title, name, count)
417 ns ± 1.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit f'Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.'
13 ns ± 0.0163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comparing Performance for all 4 ways of string formatting**

`title = 'Mr.'
name = 'Tom'
count = 3`

`%timeit 'Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.'.format(title=title, name=name, count=count)`

198 ns ± 7.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

`%timeit 'Hello {} {}! You have {} messages.'.format(title, name, count)`

329 ns ± 7.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

`%timeit 'Hello %s %s! You have %d messages.'%(title, name, count)`

264 ns ± 6.95 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

`%timeit f'Hello {title} {name}! You have {count} messages.'`

12.1 ns ± 0.0936 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

So the latest way of string formatting is from python3.6 is fastest also.