# Python3: How to use print() to print a string with quote?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to ask, how to use `print()` in python3 to print the double quote (compulsory).

The code:

```
>>> List0 = ["1", "text", 25]
>>> print(List0)
['1', 'text', 25]
>>> str0 = str(List0)
>>> print(str0)
['1', 'text', 25]
```

`str0` looks like a list but it is a string. Using `print()`, the double quotes are not shown. How to use the `print()`, but let the quotes shown? It should be like: `"['1', 'text', 25]"` ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you want to print what the string would look like if you were to assign it as a literal.  For that, use `repr`, like this:

```
print(repr(str0))
```

will print

```
"['1', 'text', 25]"
```

Comment: Since they're in the console, they can just type `str0`

Comment: yes, but the question was how to use `print()` to get this result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `json` module like so:

```
import json

list0 = ["1", "text", 25]

print(json.dumps(list0)) #=> ["1", "text", 25]
```

**Edit**

To have double quotes on the outside use Python 3.6+ string interpolation:

```
list0 = ["1", "text", 25]
print(f'"{list0}"')
"['1', 'text', 25]"
```

Comment: that doesn't add the quotes, and changes simple quotes by double quotes

Comment: you need python 3, but python 3.6 and higher, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745050/string-with-f-prefix-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 2):

`str.format` does it all very simply: list to string conversion, formatting:

```
>>> List0 = ["1", "text", 25]
>>> print('"{}"'.format(List0))
"['1', 'text', 25]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape from a string by using the character `\`:

```
print("\"['1', 'text', 25]\"")  # "['1', 'text', 25]"
```

Alternatively you can use triple quotes:

```
print('''"['1', 'text', 25]"''')  # "['1', 'text', 25]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Print will not show quotes by default in a string. You will have to add them by concatenation.

```
Print("\""+str0+"\"")
```