# How to print literal/quoted string in python for safety purpose?

Tags: python

Given the following python script:

```py
s = "hello world"
print(s)
```

When you run it you will get

```bash
hello world
```

If I want the output to be

```
"hello world"
```

Is there any build-in quote/escape method can do this? For example

```py
s = "hello world"
print(quote(s))
```

Here is my real world use case: I want to run `glob` on a remote machine via fabric. And the search pattern of `glob` is provided by user. So I need to ensure the string are quoted properly. Here is the sample code (I already know `repr` is the right method)

```py
import shlex

glob_pattern = 'some-data/*'  # user input, maybe malform

script = 'from glob import glob; print(glob({}))'.format(repr(glob_pattern))
cmd = 'python -c {}'.format(shlex.quote(script))

connection.run(cmd)  # use a fabric connection to run script on remote node
```

Comment: `print(repr(s))`?

Comment: Wow, I never think of it as I thought `repr` is just a method to show human friendly message in exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string that contains quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018995/how-to-print-a-string-that-contains-quotes-in-python)

Comment: Atually the command is build in python, the flow is:   build a dynamic python script string in python => run the python string on remote node via `fabric`

Comment: @hc_dev No, it's for static string, I am looking for a method to handle dynamic string. I just update my use case in the original question.

Comment: Python2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/how-to-print-double-quotes-around-a-variable

Python3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365860/python3-how-to-use-print-to-print-a-string-with-quote

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is --> `print(repr(s))`

Output:

`'hello world'`

You can read more about `repr()` for example here --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-repr-function/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repr` to produce a *valid literal* of your string. However, instead of producing a valid Python string literal inside a valid bash literal, you should probably pursue something like this instead:

```
from shlex import quote

command = f'''echo -n {quote(s)} | python -c 'from glob import glob; import sys; print(glob(sys.stdin.read()))'''
```

Keep your Python code static and supply arguments to it, in this case via stdin.

Comment: That's anthoer option, thank you!

Comment: This is the better solution, when taking security into consideration.

Comment: But glob is just one of my use cases, there may be cases requiring multiple params in the future. I would expected more general solution. For example, use `shlex` and environment variable instead of `stdin`.

Comment: Yes, environment variables are another option, as is passing a JSON object via stdin or whatever. You'll have to figure out the right combination for your particular case.