# Python and F-Strings explanation

Tags: python, python-3.6

In the follow f-string,

```
print("It's fleece was white as {}.".format('snow'))
```

Is `'snow'` a variable? I am confused with what exactly it would be judged as.

Comment: That's not an `f` string, that's a regular string literal on which the `str.format()` method is being called. No, `snow` is not a variable, it is another string literal.

Comment: An `f` string starts with an `f`: `print(f"It's fleece was white as {'snow'}.")`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much for your help. I am just starting out with Python and i'm attempting to wrap my head around it. Clear and concise! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `'snow'` is a string literal, an expression that produces a string value. `snow` would be a variable name (note the lack of quotes).

Compare:

```
>>> 'snow'
'snow'
>>> snow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'snow' is not defined
>>> snow = 42
>>> snow
42
>>> snow = 'snow'
>>> snow
'snow'
```

The variable snow at first wasn't yet assigned to, so trying to use it caused an exception. I then assigned an integer to the name, and then the string with value `'snow'`.

Formatting a string literal with another string literal is pretty meaningless. You'd *normally* use an actual variable, so you can vary the output produced:

```
compared_to = 'snow'
print("It's fleece was white as {}.".format(compared_to))
```

Also, that's not an `f` string. An `f` string literal starts with a `f` character. What you have here is a regular, run-of-the-mill string literal, and a call to the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). The following is the equivalent expression using an f-string:

```
print(f"It's fleece was white as {'snow'}.")
```

See [String with 'f' prefix in python-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745050/string-with-f-prefix-in-python-3-6) for more information on actual f-strings.