# Is it possible to loop through several variables that have range values?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm doing a python challenge on `101computin.net` and I can't figure out how to make my code shorter. I have tried placing these variables into a `list`, but then I can't check if the density is in the range within the list because the object can't be interpreted as an integer.

```
#Eureka! - Archimedes and King Hiero's Crown - www.101computing.net/eureka-and-king-hieros-crown/
```

```
mass = float(input("Input the mass of the crown in kg"))
volume = float(input("Input the volume of the crown in cubic meter"))

density = mass / volume

aluminum = range(2400, 2700)
bronze = range(8100, 8300)
silver = range(10400, 10600)
lead = range(11200, 11400)
gold = range(17100, 17500)
platinum = range(21000, 21500)

if density in Aluminum:
    print('Your crown is aluminum!')
elif density in bronze:
    print('B')
elif density in silver:
    print('S')
elif density in lead:
    print('L')
elif density in gold:
    print('G')
elif density in platinum:
    print('P')
else:
    print('Nope!')
```

Obviously, all the `if`/`elif` statements will work, but is there an easier way to loop through the ranges and determine which metal the output is based on the density?

Comment: Your density for gold is wrong. It should be around 19300

Comment: @fdermishin Yeah I know, I just took the values from the challenge I was doing...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
metals = {
    'aluminum': range(2400, 2700),
    'bronze': range(8100, 8300),
    'silver': range(10400, 10600)
}

for metal, values in metals.items():
    if density in values:
        print('Your crown is ' + metal + '!')
        break
else:
    print('Nope!')
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get this error: `NameError: name 'density' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary to store this ranges in it. In the example below I construct dictionary where key is a name of your product and the value is a tuple where first element is a actual range and second one is a message which should be printed:

```
mass = float(input("Input the mass of the crown in kg"))
volume = float(input("Input the volume of the crown in cubic meter"))

density = mass / volume

values = {
    'aluminium': (range(2400, 2700), 'Your crown is aluminum',
    'bronze': (range(8100, 8300), 'B'),
    'silver': (range(10400, 10600), 'S'),
    'lead': (range(11200, 11400), 'L'),
    'gold': (range(17100, 17500), 'G'),
    'platinium': (range(21000, 21500), 'P')
}


c = 0
for k,v in values.items():
    if density in v[0]:
        c += 1
        print(v[1])

if c > 0:
    print('Nope!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store the `metals`, also the `else` statement after the `for` loop covers the case in which no items are found.

```
mass = float(input("Input the mass of the crown in kg "))
volume = float(input("Input the volume of the crown in cubic meter "))

metals = {
    'aluminum': range(2400, 2700),
    'bronze': range(8100, 8300),
    'silver': range(10400, 10600),
    'lead': range(11200, 11400),
    'gold': range(17100, 17500),
    'platinum': range(21000, 21500)
}

for metal, density in metals.items():
    if mass / volume in density:
        print(f'Your crown is {metal}!')
        break
else:
    print('Nope!')
```

Output (with an input of `2400`, `1`):

```
Input the mass of the crown in kg 2400
Input the volume of the crown in cubic meter 1
Your crown is aluminum!
```

Comment: One question, why exactly is metal and density separated by a comma in the for loop?

```
    for metal, density in metals.items():

```

Comment: `metals.items()` returns list of tuples of key and value. Then these tuples are unpacked into `metal` and `density`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867882/tuple-unpacking-in-for-loops

Comment: @DevinHight For example, in the first iteration `metal` stores `'aluminum'` and `density` stores the `range` function.

Comment: Also I am using `f-strings` in my answer as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-vs-str-format
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455784/python-and-f-strings-explanation
For various reasons (performance, readability) they are considered to be better than doing a simple string concatenation.

Comment: I am also calculating the density on the fly (based on the user input) and comparing it with the density ranges, as to save more lines of code, since it's a trivial computation.

Answer (score 1):

It could probably be more optimised, but I would put the metals and their range of densities in a dictionary and iterate them.

```py
metals = {"Aluminum":range(2400, 2700),"Bronze":range(8100, 8300),"Silver":range(10400, 10600),"Lead":range(11200, 11400),"Gold":range(17100, 17500),"Platinum":range(21000, 21500)}

for metal,density in metals.items():
    if input_density in density:
        print(metal[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list approach. I do this very often when i'm working on Unity scripts.

```
mass = float(input("Input the mass of the crown in kg"))
volume = float(input("Input the volume of the crown in cubic meter"))

density = mass / volume
element_list = [range(2400,2700),range(8100,8300),range(10400,10600),range(11200,11400),range(17100,17500),range(21000,21500)]
element_list2 = ["aluminum","bronze","silver","lead","gold","platinum"]
for i in range(len(element_list)):
    if density in element_list[i]:
        print(f"Your crown made of: {element_list2[i]}")
```