# How to remove commas from printed result?

Tags: python, list, printing, format, tuples

I need to print this list without the commas, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
data = (
    ('Sabrina Bryan,1/3/98,ss9387,f9;s1;m1,99km'),
    ('Fergus Connon Archer,11/21/89,ss5246,f1;s3,102km'),
    ('Adrian Harvey,3/3/78,ss1654,m5;s2,72km'),
    ('Patricia Abigail Wolf,9/5/00,ss0936,f3;s4;m8,134km'),
    ('Georgina Kramer,6/15/95,ss4837,f5;s2;m1,55km'),
    ('Glenn Julian Ayala,3/19/90,ss3689,s4;f3,152km'),
    ('Anita Davila,6/27/91,ss9367,f8,203km'),
    ('Gertrude Nunez,1/12/97,ss3948,s3;m1,34km'),
    ('Solomon Burton,8/5/88,ss7364,s2;f1,23km'),
    ('Rafael John Murray,10/19/01,ss9105,s9;f3,78km')
)

info = input("What would you like to do? ")
if info == 'b':
    for line in data:
        fname0 = data[0].split(' ')
        lname0 = fname0[1].split(',')
        bday0 = lname0[1].split('/')

        def Sabrina(fname0, bday0):
            print(fname0[0], *bday0[0:2], sep = ', ')
        print(Sabrina(fname0, bday0))
```

It is printing "Sabrina, 1, 3" when I want it to print "Sabrina 1 3". I have tried using the `.replace` command, `*bday0[0:2].replace(',', ' ')`, but it just gives me an error. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.replace()`.

---

```
print(fname0[0], *bday0[0:2])
```

or

```
print(fname0[0], *bday0[0:2], sep = ' ')
```

will give you the desired output.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing that, it's still printing with commas in between the different elements. Edit: Never mind, I just figured out what I was doing wrong XD

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a quick solution for your problem:

It is based on the use of **F-Strings**. With this formatting-solution, you can quickly format your strings by implementing your variables without losing sight of the format of your output, also adding a return to the function.

### Function Code Snippet

```
 def Sabrina(fname0, bday0):
        return f"{fname0[0]}, {bday0[0]} {bday0[1]}"
```

Here is more information related to the [f-strings formatting explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745050/string-with-f-prefix-in-python-3-6).

It would be a great improvement if you could work around the issue that the values are hardcoded. But for a quick implementation this should help.

Let me know if this answers your question.
Cheers!

### Full Working Code-Snippet

```
data = (
('Sabrina Bryan,1/3/98,ss9387,f9;s1;m1,99km'),
('Fergus Connon Archer,11/21/89,ss5246,f1;s3,102km'),
('Adrian Harvey,3/3/78,ss1654,m5;s2,72km'),
('Patricia Abigail Wolf,9/5/00,ss0936,f3;s4;m8,134km'),
('Georgina Kramer,6/15/95,ss4837,f5;s2;m1,55km'),
('Glenn Julian Ayala,3/19/90,ss3689,s4;f3,152km'),
('Anita Davila,6/27/91,ss9367,f8,203km'),
('Gertrude Nunez,1/12/97,ss3948,s3;m1,34km'),
('Solomon Burton,8/5/88,ss7364,s2;f1,23km'),
('Rafael John Murray,10/19/01,ss9105,s9;f3,78km'))

 info = input("What would you like to do? ")
 if info == 'b':
 for line in data:
      fname0 = data[0].split(' ')
      lname0 = fname0[1].split(',')
      bday0 = lname0[1].split('/')

    def Sabrina(fname0, bday0):
        return f"{fname0[0]} {bday0[0]} {bday0[1]}"
    
    
    print(Sabrina(fname0, bday0))
```

Comment: Sorry I just realized that I forgot to remove the comma from the: f"{fname0[0]}, {bday0[0]} {bday0[1]}", it should be: f"{fname0[0]} {bday0[0]} {bday0[1]}"